# Rails 3: Modifying RESTful Controller 'Create' Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I'm trying to modify the logic within a RESTful controller. In the current implementation, I have the following:

members_controller.rb

```
def create
    @team = current_team
    player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
    @member = @team.add_player(player.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.save
            format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Member was successfully added.') }
            format.js { @current_member = @member }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @member, 
            :status => :created, :location => @member } 
      else
            format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Member already exists.') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @member.errors, 
            :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

team.rb

```
has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy

def add_player(player_id)
    current_member = members.find_by_player_id(player_id)
    if current_member
        # will not add duplicate member
    else
        current_member = members.build(:player_id => player_id)
    end
    current_member
end
```

This is lacking some functionality as I want to be able to control whether the member is saved by checking other attributes of the member against the player. In the current implementation, if I try to add a member that already exists, it is still getting redirected to @team with the notice 'Member was successfully added.', even though no member is being added. If I try to remove the redundancy by having the following, the controller adds duplicate members.

```
@team = current_team
@member = @team.add_player(:player_id)
```

Why is my current logic allowing me to not save a duplicate member, but still responding to the @member.save route? How do I control it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
def add_player(player_id)
current_member = members.find_by_player_id(player_id)
if current_member
    # will not add duplicate member
else
    current_member = members.build(:player_id => player_id)
end
current_member
end
```

Try:

Member.rb

```
validates_uniqueness_of :player_id, :scope => :team_id
```

team.rb

```
def add_player(player_id)
    current_member = members.build(:player_id => player_id)   
    current_member
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, and it's still doing the same thing, where a member is not getting saved, but it's getting redirected to the @team with the 'Member was saved' message.

Comment: Try to add this validation to your member.rb

Comment: The validation still has the same results as before. In addition to that, if it causes some errors when trying to create another Team. The way I have it set up now, multiple teams can have the same player. It just creates a separate Member for each Team that is joined to the Player.

Comment: Yeah but a member can only have a unique player_id right? I was wrong before.. Add the validation to member.rb

Comment: No problem mate:) I had a lot of problems before and someone else helped me:)

Comment: Unfortunately, I spoke to soon and it looks like it's not working as expected. After the first correct 'Member already exists' message, it won't let me add any other Team Members and always displays the 'Member already exists' message when I try to add other members. I do really appreciate your help in all of this though!

Comment: Are you trying to add another member with the same player id to another team ?

Comment: Yeah. When I'm managing another team and trying to add a player that is already a member on another team, it gives me the 'Member already exists' message. And actually, it doesn't give me the 'Member already exists' message if say I have Player_1 as a team member on the current team and try to add Player_1 again. It only gives the 'Member already exists' message when adding a duplicate player onto another team.

Comment: I modified my code.. Can you try the new version? I edited team.rb and member.rb

Comment: Nice! That allowed different Teams to add the same Players, but the 'Member already exists' message essentially never appears now now.

Comment: Oops didn't see that had changed as well. Everything is working as desired now. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem mate:) Going to sleep now:)

Answer (score 0):

ntenisOT is correct. When you're calling build inside team.rb, you're not actually saving the membership, you're only adding the player to the team on that particular team object. Also, the controller is still responding to save because you're calling save on the player which returns true.

Comment: Does this mean I need to move the build command and the associated logic to the controller?

Comment: No, ntenisOT's code is right. Changing yours to that should make it work. find_or_create_by_player_id should find and return the member if they already exist, or create and return the member if they don't.